# What is an iterator's default value?

Tags: c++, stl, default, containers, iterator

For any STL container that I'm using, if I declare an iterator (of this particular container type) using the iterator's default constructor, what will the iterator be initialised to?

For example, I have:

```
std::list<void*> address_list;
std::list<void*>::iterator iter;
```

What will iter be initialised to?

Comment: `std::list<void*>::iterator iter;` is a __definition__. While all definitions are declarations, a declaration that's not a definition would be: `extern std::list<void*>::iterator iter;`.

Comment: In particular, the constructor belongs to the _definition_, not any other declaration. This means you can pass values to the constructor only in the (single) definition. Also, if the ctor is a template (like here), it's instantiated where the definition is.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

By convention a "NULL iterator" for containers, which is used to indicate no result, compares equal to the result of `container.end()`.

```
 std::vector<X>::iterator iter = std::find(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), x);
 if (iter == my_vec.end()) {
     //no result found; iter points to "nothing"
 }
```

However, since a default-constructed container iterator is not associated with any particular container, there is no good value it could take. Therefore it is just an uninitialized variable and the only legal operation to do with it is to assign a valid iterator to it.

```
 std::vector<X>::iterator iter;  //no particular value
 iter = some_vector.begin();  //iter is now usable
```

---

For other kinds of iterators this might not be true. E.g in case of `istream_iterator`, a default-constructed iterator represents (compares equal to) an `istream_iterator` which has reached the EOF of an input stream.

Comment: There is a proposal for a value initialized iterator to exist. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3644.pdf

Comment: Under that proposal writing auto ni = vector<int>::iterator() would create a null vector<int> iterator that would compare equal to any other iterator of the same type

Comment: N3644 / null forward iterators exists since C++14. This seems to be this answer but if I understand correctly that's only for forward iterators and better (and only since C++14).

Answer (score 30):

The default constructor initializes an iterator to a *singular value*:

> Iterators can also have singular values that are not associated with any sequence.
> *[ Example:* After the declaration of an uninitialized pointer `x` (as with `int* x;`),
> `x` must always be assumed to have a singular value of a pointer. *— end example ]*
> **Results of most expressions are undefined for singular values**
> [[24.2.1 §5]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/iterators#iterator.requirements.general-5)

Comment: My standardese aversion striking again. `<sigh>` What does that mean in understandable speech?

Comment: @sbi: Well, the paragraph goes on and on, I decided to cut it. Basically, you are not allowed to do anything useful with a singular value, for example dereference it or compare it.

Comment: @sbi: just replace all instances of "singular" with "weird". You're not allowed to do anything with it because it's in a weird state.

Comment: @jalf & Fred: Thanks. Interesting. I've certainly never come across the term "singular value". Would that mean a _certain_, special value_ (as `NULL` is for pointers)? I thought `T*` is a valid type for `std::vector<T>::iterator`? (Old Dinkumware implementations used to do that.) If that was true, `std::vector<T>::iterator it;` certainly wouldn't initialize `it` to a special value, while `std::vector<T>::iterator it = std::vector<T>::iterator();` would.

Comment: It might be useful to consider singular iterators "write-only, do not point to a sequence (yet)". As they're write-only, you can't talk about "the value they have".

Comment: @sbi: For user-defined types T, the definition `T x;` **always** initializes x with the default constructor (if there is one, of course).

Comment: @jalf & @Fred: Well, the question still stands. Do you happen to know the answer?

Comment: @sbi: It is not required to have any special value, it is basically degenerate: you can't really do anything with it, other than assign to it to bring it into a well-defined non-singular state. An uninitialized pointer would be an example of a singular iterator.

Comment: @jalf: Thanks for clarifying that. I consider "singular value" a badly coined name for something that could have _any_ possible value. It sure threw me off....

Comment: The only correlation I can think of is in the linear algebra sense, e.g. a singular matrix is one with infinite solutions.

Answer (score 13):

The iterator is not initialized, just as `int x;` declares an integer which isn't initialized. It does not have a properly defined value.

Comment: Is there a way to initialise iter to NULL?

Comment: @The Void: Your question makes no sense. `NULL` is a value _pointers_ may have, bot iterators. While all pointers are iterators, not all iterators are pointers.

Comment: So, while there is such a thing as a NULL pointer, there's no such thing as a "NULL iterator"?

Comment: @The Void: An iterator is an object, and there is no such thing as a "NULL object". (Yes, there is that pattern, but that's a completely different thing.) The closest thing to a "NULL iterator" is the singular value described in my answer.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "empty" or "null" iterator. It's the same as a lock for instance. You can't talk about an "empty" or a "null" lock, this just makes no sense.

Comment: @JesperE: It most probably is initialized (iterators in many cases are classes, and they will have a default constructor that initializes the contents).

Comment: @sbi: is bot a new abbreviation for "but not"? :)

Comment: @codymanix: Yeah, something like this. I guess thinking got ahead of typing and my fingers cheated to catch up. `:)`

Comment: @fredoverflow, ironically, some (all?) standard container iterators have a constructor that take (explicitly?) a `nullptr`/`0` argument, as in `std::vector<double>::iterator vit{nullptr}; std::list<double>::iterator lit{nullptr};`. Not sure what whether it is standard (I am using gcc) and what is the purpose, (maybe to accept generic code in the initialization of a pointer?).