# std::advance behavior when advancing beyond end of container

Tags: c++, stl

What is the behavior of std::advance when you have say:

```
std::vector<int> foo(10,10);
auto i = foo.begin();
std::advance(i, 20);
```

What is the value of **i**? Is it **foo.end()**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the `foo` size by advancing to 20th position. Definitely it is not end of the vector. It should invoke *undefined behavior* on dereferencing, AFAIK.

Edit 1:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     std::vector<int> foo(10,10) ;
     std::vector<int>::iterator iter = foo.begin() ;
     std::advance(iter,20);

     std::cout << *iter << "\n" ;

     return 0;
}
```

**Output:** 0

If it is the vector's last element, then it should have given 10 on iterator dereferencing. So, it is UB.

[IdeOne Results](http://ideone.com/QpeCM)

Comment: Your example is incorrect. Even if the iterator were clamped to `end()` it still wouldn't be pointing to anything valid.

Comment: @Mark Ransom - Instead, I should have said last element in the vector. Modified the terminology and thanks for notifying.

Comment: Mark's point is that advancing to just past the last element of the vector is well-defined (though you can't dereference that iterator).  In other words using your example, if the `advance` line had been: `std::advance(iter,10)`, there wouldn't be UB at that point, though there would be when the `cout` expression was executed.  So if `advance()` were specified to somehow 'stick' on `end()` when the iterator reaches that point, your example would still show UB, but not on the call to `advance()`.

Answer (score 36):

The standard defines `std::advance()` in terms of the types of iterator it's being used on (24.3.4 "Iterator operations"):

> These function templates use + and - for random access iterators (and are, therefore, constant time for them); for input, forward and bidirectional iterators they use ++ to provide linear time implementations.

The requirements for these operations on various iterator types are also outlined in the standard (in Tables 72, 74, 75 and 76):

- For an input or forward iterator

  ```
  ++r precondition: r is dereferenceable
  ```
- for a bidirectional iterator:

  ```
  --r precondition: there exists s such that r == ++s
  ```
- For random access iterators, the `+`, `+=`, `-`, and `-=` operations are defined in terms of the bidirectional & forward iterator prefix `++` and `--` operations, so the same preconditions hold.

So advancing an iterator beyond the 'past-the-end' value (as might be returned by the `end()` function on containers) or advancing before the first dereferenceable element of an iterator's valid range (as might be returned by `begin()` on a container) is undefined behavior since you're violating the preconditions of the `++` or `--` operation.

Since it's undefined behavior you can't 'expect' anything in particular.  But you'll likely crash at some point (hopefully sooner rather than later, so you can fix the bug).

Answer (score 10):

According to the C++ Standard §24.3.4 `std::advance(i, 20)` has the same effect as `for ( int n=0; n < 20; ++n ) ++i;` for positive `n`. From the other side (§24.1.3) if `i` is past-the-end, then `++i` operation is undefined. So the result of `std::advance(i, 20)` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

That is probably undefined behavior. The only thing the standard says is:

Since only random access iterators provide + and - operators, the library provides two function templates advance and distance. These function templates use + and - for random access iterators (and are, therefore, constant time for them); for input, forward and bidirectional iterators they use ++ to provide linear time implementations.

```
template <class InputIterator, class Distance> 
void advance(InputIterator& i, Distance n);
```

Requires: n shall be negative only for bidirectional and random access iterators. Effects: Increments (or decrements for negative n) iterator reference i by n.

Answer (score 1):

From the SGI page for [std::advance](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/advance.html):

> Every iterator between i and i+n
>   (inclusive) is nonsingular.

Therefore i is not foo.end() and dereferencing will result in undefined behavior.

Notes:

1. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441893/what-is-singular-and-non-singular-values-in-the-context-of-stl-iterators) for more details about what (non)singular means when referring to iterators.
2. I know that the SGI page is not the de-facto standard but pretty much all STL implementations follow those guidelines.