# Remove all the vector elements apart from the 'largest' one

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Given a vector such as this:

```
struct product {
    float price;
    float shipping;
};

vector<product> products;
```

how can I remove all the products from the vector apart from the one with the largest `shipping` to `price` ratio?

I tried keeping an iterator to the highest one found so far...

```
vector<product>::iterator it = products.begin();
vector<product>::iterator largest = products.begin();

while (it != products.end())
{
    if (it->shipping / it->price > largest->shipping / largest->price)
    {
        products.erase(largest);
        largest = it;
        ++it;
    }
    else
    {
        it = products.erase(it);
    }
}
```

This is all well and good but it fails if the first element in the vector has the highest ratio (it gets deleted). I could get around the problem (I think) if `largest` was uninitialized and then checking for that in the `if` statement, but there is no real way of doing this from what I can tell ([How to check if the iterator is initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954949/how-to-check-if-the-iterator-is-initialized)).

Any suggestions?

Comment: how big is the vector<product> ?

Comment: Just initialize `it` to `products.begin() + 1`.

Comment: not too big... max of 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 vector<product> products;
 //populate products

 products.erase(
      products.begin(),
      std::max_element(
          product.begin(), 
          producted.end()
      )
 );
 products.resize(1u);
```

This assume you have a suitable operator< for your type, if not, make a comparison function and provide it as the third param to max_element.

EDIT:

This work also, in this case, instead of explicitly find the element and delete the element either side, it will sort to find 1 elemnt, then we can do one erase.

```
 vector<product> products;
 //populate products
 std::nth_element(
      products.begin(), 
      products.begin()+1, 
      products.end(), 
      std::greater<product>()
 );
 products.resize(1u);
```

Comment: You don't need the second call to `max_element`; after the first `erase` maximum value is the first element. So `products.erase( ++products.begin(), products.end() );` will do the trick.

Comment: I think I'd use `std::swap` to move the maximum element to the beginning of the collection, then delete the rest (could be substantially faster, especially for `vector`).

Comment: that's why I ask how big is the vector :D

Comment: actually the nicest way in that respect would be to do `nth_element`, to sort to 1 element, then erase.

Comment: Or, to also get rid of the extra allocated space: `std::vector<product>(1, products.back()).swap(products);`.

Comment: `products.assign(1, *std::max_element(product.begin(), producted.end());`

Comment: @jrok, the cost of the allocation is probably more than the wasted space, although that is context specific.

Comment: @MooingDuck, Nice, but you use three different names for `products`.

Comment: @MooingDuck that would mean at least one copy, I think the nth_element way would be moved.

Comment: @chris: I'm at a complete loss as to how/why that happened.

Comment: @MooingDuck, It's funny to realize what our brains can do when we're not looking :)

Comment: Your second call to `products.erase(...)` could be simplified to `products.resize(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite the code to only make *one single deletion*:

```
std::vector<product>::iterator largest = products.begin();

for (std::vector<product>::iterator it = products.begin(); it != products.end(); ++it)
{
    if (...) { largest = it; }
}

products.erase(it);
```

Comment: say that my vector has 10 elements. how will one single deletion remove 9 of them (there is only one with the largest ratio which should be left)?

Comment: @zoran119: You need two passes. Determine the *value* of the largest ratio first, and then delete all those elements. Use `std::remove_if` for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could define `largest` as the first element and start iteration from the second element, just as followings:

```
bool operator < (const struct product& p1, const struct product& p2)
{
   return p1.price/p1.shipping < p2.price/p2.shipping;
}

vector<product>::iterator largest = products.begin();
vector<product>::iterator it = products.begin();
++it;

while (it != products.end())
{
    if (*largest < *it)
    {
        products.erase(largest);
        largest = it;
        ++it;
    }
    else
    {
        it = products.erase(it);
    }
 }
```

But there is a bug here, after `products.erase(largest)` is called, `it` will be invalidated, so you'd better take the approach other suggested here.