# std::map iterator initialization by zero in C++

Tags: c++, iterator

I need to initialize an interator by zero value. I tried following code

```
#include <map>
std::map<int, int>::iterator foo() {
    std::map<int, int>::iterator ret;
    ret = std::map<int, int>::iterator(0);
    return ret;
}
```

It successfully compiled by gcc and intel C++ compilers on Linux. Also, this compiled well in minGW on Windows. The code provided with -O2 is

```
xorl eax, eax
ret
```

The issue is compilation under VisualStudio. The error is:
error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'std::_Tree_iterator>>> No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous.

Could you please give me an idea how to cast zero or rephrase initialization of iterator?

Thank you

PS

main idea is getting NULL at the end of the "list"

> (it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); it = it->next)

that based on map::iterators from diffrent map objects.

```
a::end() {
    return std::map<K, V>::iterator(0)
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to initialize it to `0`?

Comment: Just what do you think initialising an iterator to 0 would *mean?* Can you explain your scenario? This looks very much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/201677).

Comment: Maybe this ist helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395180/what-is-an-iterators-default-value

Comment: "Why do you need to initialize it to 0" - I need same iterator to make != operation in many cases in my programm

Comment: "what do you think initialising an iterator to 0 would mean?" - I need "return NULL" but with ::iterator paradigm

Comment: That is not possible. Probably you need a totally different approach. What Problem do you need to solve with this solution?

Comment: Sorry, but the original problem is huge to explain. Shortly, I have map< K1, map<K, V> >. Each internal map is long queue for analysis. The values of V is large struct with map::iterator next and map::iterator begin fields. Some time, depends on internal meaning of the V element, I need to iterate over V located in different super map (map<K1, map..>). It something like columns in matrix if rows are different std::map objects. So, I need to set NULL at the last V.next to get a reason to stop iterating over it – for(it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it = it->next) {}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, you don't.**

You need to initialize either with *past-the-end* value (which you can only get from the container it is supposed to iterate):

```
return map.end();
```

or at worst with *default* value:

```
return std::map<int, int>::iterator();
```

The difference is that the former can be tested whether it is end iterator, while the later is basically untouchable. If you do the later, you basically have to remember not to touch it. You can't even compare default-constructed iterators for equality to check that they are default-constructed (most implementations define the comparison, but some may not).

Comment: You might want to point out that using `==` on a default-constructed iterator need not be well-defined.

Comment: "initialize either with past-the-end value"
What is it or how it implemented in std::map?

return map.end();
Is this value is the same for diffrent map objects? I suspect it could point to some elements inside map structures and couldn't be the same.

Comment: It's not the same. And there is no null value that you can use.

Comment: @shs_sf Yes, it's specific to the `std::map` object from which it was taken. But don't you have one in your class anyway?

Comment: @shs_sf: Yes the value might be different. There is no universal "NULL-Iterator".

Comment: @shs_sf: It has to be specific to the container, because the past-the-end value can be decremented to get the last element if there is one.

Comment: I just tried to compile default iterator initialization - it compiles as I mentioned in the post - return zero. Sorry for this stupid questions. One more thing "using == on a default-constructed iterator need not be well-defined" - why?

Comment: @shs_sf because the standard doesn't guarantee that is does.