# Default constructed map iterator enters infinite loop on increment - Green Hills compiler

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap, greenhills

I have to do a trivial iteration of all the elements in a std::map, first to last. On each element I have to perform an operation. Assume that the map contains the following pairs:

```
map<string,string> farm={
                        {"one","puppy"},
                        {"two","kitty"},
                        {"three","sheepy"}
                       }
```

The bit of code that performs the iteration is the following:

```
for(map<string,string>::iterator beast; beast!=farm.end(); ++beast) 
{
     feed(*beast);
}
```

Now the surprise is that the above code works for the first element (`puppy` is fed) but the iterator fails to go to the next elements. The debugger shows that `++beast` never returns (seems like it is recursively branching on its left leaf forever).

It seems that the issue here is that `beast` is never assigned to `farm.begin()` and as such it can't progress to the next item (see first element of the for).

So here are my questions:

- Is it normal that the default constructor of a map iterator automatically positions the object to point to the `map.begin()` element?
- If that is common practice, then why a valid first element is
  returned (it could have been returned `map.end()` for example) ?
- How could the `operator++` be allowed to quietly fail in an infinite loop? Wouldn't be better to return with an error code (we disabled
  exceptions) or fail openly somehow ?

I wonder if the standard allows this kind of behaviours or it is an implementation choice.

*Assumptions:* I am not using C++11, I am using Green Hills compiler v2016 with execption support disabled

**EDIT:**

I am trying to understand why I get a valid value and a quiet fail as in other threads people suggest that a default-constructed iterator is assigned to `map.end()`. Does the standard gives guidance on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an iterator's default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395180/what-is-an-iterators-default-value)

Comment: Undefined behavior,  So expect anything to happen.

Comment: @GauravSehgal thank you for pointing that post to me because in my case it is happening exactly the opposite of what that post describes (I get a not-incrementable map.begin() instead of a more logical map.end() ), and I am asking what's the logic behind this and why it fails quietely

Comment: Try to use a STL algorithms instead of raw loops.

Comment: @Assimazza -- Change compiler options, and the behavior may change again.

Comment: @manni66 any suggested algorithm?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I could escalate the question even more, if it is undefined behaviour then what's the point of allowing a default constructor for iterator

Comment: @Assimazza C++ allows you to do all sorts of things that are undefined behavior.  Declaring an iterator that isn't hooked into a container is valid code.  The bug is yours for not doing so, not C++.

Comment: Try std::for_each

Comment: _what's the point of allowing a default constructor for iterator_ `map<string,string>::iterator i; if(useA) i = a.begin(); else i = b.begin();`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't question my error, I question why I got a map.beign(), which fooled me around for a few hours, instead of a map.end() which would have pointed me straight to the problem. I think undefined behaviour answers the question, thanks

Comment: There doesn't exist **a** map::end(). Every map has it's own. You are not allowed to compare iterators originating from different maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it normal that the default constructor of a map iterator
>   automatically positions the object to point to the map.begin()
>   element?

No, you should initialize it properly:

```
for(map<string,string>::iterator beast = farm.begin(); beast!=farm.end(); ++beast)
```

Btw there is no way that the compiler can know that you want `map<string,string>::iterator beast` to be an iterator for `farm`, of course you need to get an iterator from the container and not just create an iterator and assume it points to the container you wish.

Comment: The question is not what to do, the question is why it defaulted to a valid value (.begin() ) instead of defaulting to a clearly invalid one (such as .end() )

Comment: Tobi303 you got exactly why I am so puzzled. How did it know that it should be pointing to farm and yet it got me the first valid pair? Maybe there is some other issue here....

Comment: @Assimazza "The question is..." you should ask one question per question. I concentrated on the first, as the others just follow from a wrong assumption that in the presence of Undefined behaviour (incrementing an uninitialized iterator) one could reason about what is going on

Comment: A proper initialisation fixes the problem with no side effects, but I am really intrigued on how the heck it is possible for a default constructed iterator to point to the first element of a collection never seen before. Some memory black magic possibly

Comment: @Assimazza dont overthink it, it is plain UB nothing more. You are simply not allowed to do `++beast` if `beast` is uninitialized. The compiler notices that you broke the rules and can do whatever he feels like

Comment: It did not "default to a valid value". A default-constructed iterator has a **singular** value; it cannot be dereferenced nor incremented. Code that does either of those has undefined behavior -- you cannot infer anything meaningful from doing that.