# C++ using default-initialized iterators to create an empty std::string

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer

Is the following code valid and well-defined?

```
auto start = std::string::const_iterator();
auto end = std::string::const_iterator();

auto output = std::string(start, end);
```

(The expected output being an empty string.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an iterator's default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395180/what-is-an-iterators-default-value)

Comment: I guess there is no guarantee two default constructed (if possible) iterator should compare equal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to cppreference.com, a random access iterator, of which a string iterator is one, [meets all requirements of a bidirectional iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

Furthermore, a bidirectional iterator [meets all requirements of a forward iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator).

Finally, since C++14, a forward iterator [can be value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator), and will compare equal to all other value-initialized forward iterators of the same type:

> A value-initialized LegacyForwardIterator behaves like the
>   past-the-end iterator of some unspecified empty container: it compares
>   equal to all value-initialized LegacyForwardIterators of the same
>   type.

Based on that, I believe this is well-defined at least as of C++14.

Comment: Good to know that singular iterators are required by C++14 standard, +1.

Comment: I thought there was a requirement that iterators in a range point into the same container.

Comment: @RichardCritten The cited wording abides by such a requirement; well, at least, if we assume that we always get the _same_ unspecified empty container. Heh.

Comment: Addedndum: This guarantee does not extend to default-initialized iterators.